# FD interchangeability between Shimano 105 and Claris

Tags: shimano, compatibility, derailleur-front

I would like to ask if I can change my FD into a Shimano 105 and my crank will then be Shimano Claris? Will there be any problem with it? I was supposed to buy a 105 crank but then my FD broke, so I would use the budget for FD first.

Comment: A mechanical FD isn't a critical part. It should be fine.

Comment: What’s your front shifter? 105 will not work with Claris.

Comment: Which 105 version? Which Claris version? Not all 105 have the same cable pull ratio and not all Claris do either. How many speeds?